# Cannot find module when building

Tags: typescript, build, typeorm

I am developing a project with a few friends and we are having a `Cannot find module` when running the build. The details of the error:

```
(node:30892) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/run_main.js:54
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/home/pedro/dev/COVID/backend/build/app' imported from /home/pedro/dev/COVID/backend/build/server.js
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:284:11)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:665:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:755:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:97:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:243:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:46:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:45:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

My tsconfig:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
        "es5",
        "es6",
        "DOM"
      ],
      "target": "esnext",
      "module": "ES6",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "outDir": "./build",
      "removeComments": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",

      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true
   }
}
```

Does someone know what is wrong?

Answer (score -1):

My friend found the fix for the problem using this `tsconfig.json`

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "lib": [
         "es5",
         "es6",
         "DOM"
      ],
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"]
   }
}
```

After that, we are having a weird bug with imports, and after some time my friend noticed that the connection creator was importing the path to the models from `/src/model/**/*.ts` and after changint the `.ts` to `.js` everything works fine.